# Ordinary Differential Equations: v=dx/dt

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

The question is: What ODE does v=dx/dt solve? And what is the limit as t approaches infinity of v(t). It sounds almost too easy, but I am confused about what to do exactly. Intuitively, as the question is about falling objects I would expect the limit to go to infinity but I am not sure which ODE is the correct one to give this answer...

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that $\textbf{x}(t)$ is the particles position function and from first year calculus,

$$\frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\textbf{x}(t+h) - \textbf{x}(t)}{h}$$

However, the above also has the geometric interpretation as a displacement vector on the trajectory graph of $\textbf{x}(t)$ i.e the velocity vector and so we also call this quantity $\textbf{v}(t)$. In the image below, replace $\textbf{r}$ with $\textbf{x}$. The trajectory graph is the curved segment.

[image]

$$\textbf{v}(t):=\frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\textbf{x}(t+h) - \textbf{x}(t)}{h}$$

Hence the ODE is asking you to find such an $\textbf{x}$ given $\textbf{v}$. Your equation is separable, in which we know how to find the solution.

$$\textbf{v}(t) = \frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt} \Rightarrow \int \textbf{v}(t) \ dt = \int d\textbf{x} = \textbf{x}+ \vec{a}$$

where $\vec{a}$ is a constant vector.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of "falling objects" one may let $x$ denote the distance above the ground in some unit of distance such as meters and $t$ to denote the time in some convenient unit, such as seconds.

In such a situation the object is under a constant gravitational force $g$ which, since the object is falling, causes $x$ to decrease as time $t$ increases. In this situation (neglecting any atmospheric drag) $x$ will accelerate $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ at a constant rate given by

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-g\tag{1}$$

The velocity of the object at time $t$ is the anti-derivative of the acceleration

$$v=\frac{dx}{dt}=-gt+v(0)\tag{2}$$

where $v(0)$ is the velocity at time $t=0$. If the object was merely dropped from some initial height $x(0)$, then $v(0)=0$. If it was thrown (either upwards or downwards) then $v(0)\ne0$.

The anti-derivative of $v(t)$ gives the height $x(t)$ above the ground at time $t$

$$x(t)=-g\cdot\frac{t^2}{2}+v(0)t+x(0)\tag{3}$$

where $x(0)$ is the initial height of the object above the ground (that is, when $t=0$.

In summary, in the context of falling objects, $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ denotes the velocity of the falling object at some time $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean for the velocity $v$ to be constant?

If not, then *given the position* as a function of time $x(t)$, we can compute the *velocity* at each time $t$
$$
 v(t) = \dot{x}(t).
$$
Solve the ODE involves integrating the *velocity* to find the *position* at each time $t$ in the domain:
$$
 \int^{t} v(\tau) d\tau = x(t)
$$
In terms of falling, your time may be finite; it will impact at some point.